# Cohomology class of zero set of a section

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Say we have a rank $r$ smooth vector bundle $E\to X$ and a smooth section $s:X\to E$ of it. Shortly after the 30 min mark in [this video](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~visita16/ELGA-2011/version/v1/images-ind-c13-en.shtml) Joe Harris defines the $r$th Chern class of this bundle to be *the cohomology class* $c_r(E)=[x:s(x)=0]$ of points where the section vanishes.

I believe this is the Poincaré dual to the homology class defined by the vanishing locus of the section, and I'd like to know how to explicitly build this homology class, and seeing why it has degree $2r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be assuming the section is transverse to the zero section. In that case, transversality says that the intersection is of $4r = \text{codim}_{TE} X \cap s(X) = \text{codim}_{TE} X + \text{codim}_{TE} s(X) = 2r+2r$. (Note that $E$ is a complex vector bundle, so the zero section has codimension $2r$, not $r$!) Then $\dim X \cap s(X) = n+2r-4r = n-2r$. This is an oriented submanifold; triangulating it with simplices whose orientations agree with the manifold. The sum of these is a chain in $X$, giving a homology class of degree $n-2r$. Poincare duality sends it to a cohomology class of degree $2r$, as requested.

As for why this is well-defined: Given two different transverse sections $s_i$, there is a transverse section $s_t: X \times I \to E$. So the resulting submanifolds $X \cap s_i(X)$ are *cobordant* via the oriented cobordism $\cup_t X \cap s_t(X)$. Triangulating this cobordism shows that the two homology classes the submanifolds $s_i(X)$ represent are homologous.

Comment: You could also construct the homology class of the submanifold as the pushforward of the fundamental class by the inclusion, right?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese That's fair. That's exactly the same as what I'm doing here, I'm just giving an explicit definition of the fundamental class.

Comment: Fair enough. $ $

Comment: Hi Mike, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'd imagine a reference for all this is the book by Guillemin and Pollack, yet I need to ask if you suggest any other reference.
Regarding Michael's comment let me see if I understand what he means: By considering the transverse intersection as a manifold by itself, it has a fundamental class in its top cohomology group. Mapping this class under the induced map in homology (covariant) by inclusion would yield exactly the same result as what you just explained, furthermore, the construction you did is precisely unwrapping this approach?

Comment: @user347489 He was suggesting I push forward the fundamental class in homology (as you say, cohomology goes in the wrong direction) by the inclusion map and then dualize. My contribution was pointing out that a fundamental class of $M$ in singular homology is given by triangulating with the appropriate orientation and summing them all up. I doubt G&P say anything about Chern classes, but Griffiths and Harris might (probably?) does this.

Comment: I don't know if G&H takes this approach on Chern classes, AFAIK they define it as the connection morphism of the exponential exact sequence, with connections, and perhaps using the Atiyah class, I'm not sure, Huybrechts does this one too. My request is for the differential topology involved in your answer, of which my knowledge is pretty poor.

Comment: I see. All you need is a transversality theorem for sections of bundles. I honestly don't know a reference for that, but if you read G&P's transversality section, the case of achieving transversality of sections of bundles is a nice (but not entirely trivial) exercise.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!